# I'm looking for a book about a guy that enters into medieval place to save a princess through a virtual reality computer game

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

I am looking for the title of a book that feature a man who uses virtual reality equipment set up to his computer to play a game. Once there, he is immersed in a virtual medieval world and becomes a knight who fights other knights and a demon in order to save a princess.

I got this book from my school library around 1996.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? For example, when did you read this? It might take some more details to identify this story.

Comment: it was in 1996ish and I borrowed the book from my school library

Comment: Did he become a demon or fight one?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [Killobyte](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441444253) by Piers Anthony?

> Not so much a novel as a series of situational puzzles, this stand-alone book by the bestselling author of the Xanth series features two characters who play a computer-generated virtual reality game called Killobyte. Walter Toland, an incapacitated former policeman, and Baal Curran, an angst-ridden, diabetic teenage girl, get to know each other as they enter into a game that calls for them to rescue a princess from a castle. But then they find themselves trapped inside the simulation by a hacker named Phoney Phreak. While the character-bodies they wear in the computer world are in no danger, their real bodies--Baal's weakened by diabetes and Walter's by a bad heart--are very much at risk. Written in Anthony's usual glib style, the novel is unimaginative in the extreme. Watching these paper-thin characters solve uninteresting puzzles is a maddening bore; and gaping holes in the plot, technological inconsistencies and Anthony's apparent ignorance of current methods of treating diabetes combine to make this one of his weakest efforts.

Comment: Yes that sounds about right ill look into it thank you

Comment: Killobyte is about VR but not about medieval setting or knights!

Comment: The cover of the book is a guy with a sword and shield fighting a dragon... that said, it covers several different regions, fantasy worlds, semi-real worlds.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is thread is old, but the book you're looking for might also be called *Demons Don't Dream*, another Piers Anthony book with a very similar plot.

Comment: Can you add any more details to explain how it matches?